# How do i get my links to be near the logo?

Tags: html, css

I want the links in the navigation bar to sit beside the logo and get another link to the right -which is not beside the other links- which writes "Text". I want an explaination to the solution as it would help me if I stumble upon this again. I am very new to stackoverflow btw.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#showcase {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./images/BackgroundShowcase.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#showcase h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  top: 350px;
}

#slideshow .Slides {
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 15%;
  height: 200px;
}

.boxes {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.box img {
  width: 175px;
  height: 150px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear: left;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mukhtar's Photography | Home </title>
  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="branding">
      <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
    </div>
    <nav id="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="PhotoGallery.html">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Photography</h2>
      <p>Our photo's are always presente in the best quality possible with carefulness
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/CameraIcon.png">
      <h2>Photography</h2>
      <p>Our photographers will always find the perfect photo whether it is a simple click to a full on video</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/CommunityICON.jpg">
      <h2>Guranteed!</h2>
      <p>If you are not satisfied with our work you will have an 80% refund</p>


    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/TimeIcon.png">
      <h2>Time Managment</h2>
      <p>Time management is a crucial step so we are always trying our best to finish up the work quickly, but surely</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BRgzXW

Comment: yes thanks for the answer

Comment: np. i'll submit as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap the logo and nav in a new element (`.d-inline-block`), set it to `display: inline-flex` (which will put the logo and nav in a row), then add a link inside of the header. Since the header is `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` and the logo and nav will be on the left in one element, that will be on the left and the new "text" link will be on the right.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#showcase {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./images/BackgroundShowcase.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#showcase h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  top: 350px;
}

#slideshow .Slides {
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 15%;
  height: 200px;
}

.boxes {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.box img {
  width: 175px;
  height: 150px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear: left;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.d-inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mukhtar's Photography | Home </title>
  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="d-inline-flex">
      <div id="branding">
        <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
      </div>
      <nav id="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="PhotoGallery.html">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <a href="#">text</a>
  </header>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Photography</h2>
      <p>Our photo's are always presente in the best quality possible with carefulness
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/CameraIcon.png">
      <h2>Photography</h2>
      <p>Our photographers will always find the perfect photo whether it is a simple click to a full on video</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/CommunityICON.jpg">
      <h2>Guranteed!</h2>
      <p>If you are not satisfied with our work you will have an 80% refund</p>


    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/TimeIcon.png">
      <h2>Time Managment</h2>
      <p>Time management is a crucial step so we are always trying our best to finish up the work quickly, but surely</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```